# Reverse DNS Delegation from ISP

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, reverse-dns, cidr

I get a /29 Delegated to me from Verizon(Fios) and I got them to delegate rDNS to my Name servers, I Notice that with some systems that it works and is able to get my PTR record, but on some it isn't able to get the PTR. Is this just a issue with [RFC 2317](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt) or is it possible for me to fix? I run Bind on Centos.

Comment: Can you give us more information on what's happening at the sites where this isn't working (i.e. what does their DNS server return? a stale PTR from Verizon, Failure, something else entirely?) -- There may be some systems out there that don't do the Right Thing and follow CNAMEs to get PTR records, but I can't imagine that to be common...

Comment: When Using web based checks such as WhatIsMYIP it just returns no PTR, I will check on a windows box when I get home in ~15. But in general I notice that it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Verizon has delegated the PTR to your nameserver it should be working in all cases.

You can always check the PTR delegation by querying ARIN database at http://www.arin.net and making sure that there's not other NS records on the delegation zone (which could be why sometimes it's not working).

If this is a recent delegation it could be also due to caching, check ARIN database, wait for a couple of days if needed :)

Comment: They did this several weeks ago, I am not sure I understand the querying ARIN as it is only 8 IPs and they just set it up as a  96.248.1.1 in addr.arpa in NS mynameserver.

Comment: Hm if I try to do an NS request for `1.1.248.96.in-addr.arpa` it shows Verizon DNS servers as the only authoritative servers for this, could you please try this? `dig NS 1.1.248.96.in-addr.arpa` or any other IP of the range they assigned you and see which Nameserver it says you should be using?

Comment: I used my gateway as an example the real IP is 96.248.216.58.

Comment: Found your record http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-96-248-216-56-1.html but as you see the Nameservers field is empty, looks like Verizon forgot to add the nameservers there :(

Comment: But arin wont enter ns for under/24 at least that's what I thought. They have to enter a in ns at their server. But I may be wrong

Comment: It returns no NS record at all for that PTR, that's what's making me very suspicious, try to contact Verizon to see what the guys say

Comment: Couldn't it be due to the fact that its inheriting from the class C info?

Answer (score 0):

Talking to voretaq7 in chat we discovered the fact that Verizon was doing everything right but that request would hit ns1 which didn't have a PTR for some reason and quit.